Finding a circle's circumference via $\lim_{n \to \infty} n r \sqrt{2 \left(1 - \cos(360^\circ/n)\right)}$, without using $\pi$
Say I have an equal-sided n-polygon inside a circle. To calculate the side length, I can see it as part of an isosceles triangle with vertex angle = 360/n and two legs' length = r
So, by using law of cosines, and having s as the base length, we get:
$$s^2 = r^2 + r^2 - 2r \cdot r \cdot \cos\left(\frac{360^\circ}{n}\right)$$
$$s = r \sqrt{2 \left(1 - \cos\left(\frac{360^\circ}{n}\right)\right)}$$
The circumference of the circle can be said to be:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot r \sqrt{2 \left(1 - \cos\left(\frac{360^\circ}{n}\right)\right)}$$
But now I'm stuck.

How to solve for this limit without using the concept of pi at all?

This means no converting to radians, for example. And also, no using areas or the definition of pi, etc. I just want to focus on this limit, and pi shouldn't appear anywhere in the solution.
What I'm expecting is that the answer to this limit is in the format of $r \cdot x$, where $x$ is some constant that somehow when numerically evaluated equals to 6.28...

You could use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac 12$ but this works in radians

What are you talking about "no pi at all", when $360°$ equals $2 \pi$? :-)

Note: The expression within the limit simplifies to $2nr\sin(180^\circ/n)$ (why?), which may be easier to think about.

Given the answer is in terms of $\pi,$ it is unclear how you can do it without knowing what $\pi$ is.

If you don't have the concept of $\pi$, you can solve numerically the above limit. Assuming that the limit exists, it is the same for any subsequence. In particular, use $n=2^k$, where you can use the half angle formula.
